# Favorability of alloca for array allocation vs simple [] array declaration

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, memory-management

Reading some Apple code, I stumbled upon the following C chunk

`alloca(sizeof(CMTimeRange) * 3)`

is this the same thing as allocation stack memory via

`CMTimeRange *p = CMTimeRange[3]` ?

Is there any implications on performance? The need to free the memory?

Comment: I think you mean `CMTimeRange someVariableName[3]`?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of the code around that call for a little context pls?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as Joachim points out you mean `CMTimeRange someVariableName[3]`...

Both will allocate memory on the stack.

I'm guessing `alloca()` will have to add extra code after your function prologue to do the allocation... The function prologue is code that the compiler automatically generates for you to create room on the stack. The upshot is that your function may be slightly larger once compiled but not by much... a few extra instructions to modify the stack pointer and possibly stack frame. I guess a compiler could optimize the call out if it wasn't in a conditional branch, or just even lift it outside of a conditional branch though?

I experimented on my MQX compiler with no optimisations... it's not objective-c, just C, also a different platform, but hopefully that's a good enough approximation and does show a difference in emitted code. I used two simple functions with a large array on the stack to make sure stack space had to be used (variable couldn't exist solely in registers).

*Obviously it is not advisable to put large arrays on the stack... this is just for demo purposes.*

```
unsigned int TEST1(unsigned int stuff)
{
    unsigned int a1[100]; // Make sure it must go on stack
    unsigned int a2[100]; // Make sure it must go on stack
    a1[0] = 0xdead;
    a2[0] = stuff + 10;
    return a2[0];
}

unsigned int TEST2(unsigned int stuff)
{
    unsigned int a1[100]; // Make sure it must go on stack
    unsigned int *a2 = alloca(sizeof(unsigned int)*100);
    a1[0] = 0xdead;
    a2[0] = stuff + 10;
    return a2[0];
}
```

The following assembler was generated:

**TEST1:**
Both arrays `a1` and `a2` are put on the stack in the function prologue...

```
   0: 1cfcb6c8                 push %fp
   4: 230a3700                 mov  %fp,%sp
   8: 24993901                 sub3 %sp,%sp,100    # Both arrays put on stack
   c: 7108                     mov_s    %r1,%r0
   e: 1b38bf98 0000dead        st   0xdead,[%fp,0xffff_fce0]        ; 0xdead
  16: e00a                     add_s    %r0,%r0,10
  18: 1b9cb018                 st   %r0,[%fp,0xffff_fe70]
  1c: 240a36c0                 mov  %sp,%fp
  20: 1404341b                 pop  %fp
  24: 7ee0                     j_s  [%blink]
```

**TEST2:**
Only array `a1` is put on the stack in the proglogue... Extra lines of code have to be generated to deal with the `alloca`.

```
   0: 1cfcb6c8                 push %fp
   4: 230a3700                 mov  %fp,%sp
   8: 24593c9c                 sub3 %sp,%sp,50 # Only one array put on stack
   c: 240a07c0                 mov  %r4,%blink
  10: 220a0000                 mov  %r2,%r0
  14: 218a0406                 mov  %r1,0x190       # Extra for alloca()
  18: 2402305c                 sub  %sp,%sp,%r1     # Extra for alloca()
  1c: 08020000r                bl   _stkchk         # Extra for alloca()
  20: 738b                     mov_s    %r3,%sp # Extra, r3 to access write via pointer
  22: 1b9cbf98 0000dead        st   0xdead,[%fp,0xffff_fe70]        ; 0xdead
  2a: 22400280                 add  %r0,%r2,10
  2e: a300                     st_s %r0,[%r3] # r3 to access write via pointer
  30: 270a3100                 mov  %blink,%r4
  34: 240a36c0                 mov  %sp,%fp
  38: 1404341b                 pop  %fp
  3c: 7ee0                     j_s  [%blink]
```

Also you `alloca()` memory will be accessed through pointers (unless there are clever compiler optimisations for this... I don't know) so causes actual memory access. Automatic variables might be optimized to being just register accesses, which is better... the compiler can figure out using register colouring what automatic variables are best left in registers and if they ever need to be on the stack.

I had a quick search through C99 standard (C11 is about... my reference is out of date a little). Could not see a reference to `alloca` so maybe not a standard-defined function. A possible disadvantage?

Comment: Why does `alloca()` require extra code compared to the *dynamic array* version?

Comment: If your function prologue decreases SP by say 5 for all the automatic variables and then, *assuming compiler doesn't optimise*, the alloca() has to generate another SP -= size. It's a tiny extra bit of code but OP asked for differences.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Presumably the compiler has to alter the stack frame in order to accommodate the dynamic array so I would assume the code is pretty similar.

Comment: Hmm... actually I was being silly and assuming both... but assuming there is at least one *other* automatic variable I think the point still stands. Say I have 4-bytes of automatic variables. Prologue does `SP -= (4 + x)`, `x` for other bits and bobs in the frame. Then say `alloca(4 bytes)`, another statement must be generated to do a *second* `SP -= 4`. Now, possibly, compilers can see the `alloca(...)` call and just emit one `SP -= 8`, but then again maybe not. Again, I realize this is an insignificant difference... does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to allocate `3` elements of something on the stack the use of `alloca` makes no sense at all. It only makes sense if you have a variable length that depends on some dynamic parameter at runtime, or if you do an unknown number of such allocations in the same function.

`alloca` is not a standard function and differs from platform to platform. The C standard has prefered to introduce VLA, variable length arrays as a replacement.

Comment: Hi Jens, small note: C11 has reduced VLAs to optional. Only required in C99

Comment: @Jimbo, the only big player that doesn't implement VLA is MS, and there is no C11 compiler from them in sight. All others have it in their compilers, they will not remove that feature.

Comment: ok good to know, thanks. It had been pointed out to me last time I mentioned VLAs. Looks like the pragmatic answer is VLAs supported then, although potentially dropped in future but I guess thats an unknown or unlikely if a vendor has already implemented VLAs as you say

Answer (score 0):

> is this the same thing as allocation stack memory via...

I would think not quite.  Declaring a local variable causes the memory to be reserved when the stack frame is entered (by subtracting the size of variable from the stack pointer and adjusting for alignment).

It looks like [alloca(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/alloca.3.html) works by adjusting the stack pointer at the moment it is encountered.  Note the "Bugs" section of the man page.

> alloca() is machine and compiler dependent; **its use is discouraged.**
>
> **alloca() is slightly unsafe** because it cannot ensure that the pointer returned points to a valid and usable block of memory.  The allocation made may exceed the bounds of the stack, or even go further into other objects in memory, and alloca() cannot determine such an error.  Avoid alloca() with large unbounded allocations.

These two points together add up to the following in my opinion:

**DO NOT USE ALLOCA**